# Requiring from lib/GEM_NAME in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I have a Gem which has the following structure:

```
gem
|
|- lib/
   |
   |- gem.rb
   |- gem/
      |
      |- router.rb
```

Inside `gem.rb`, there's the following code:

```
module Gem
    VERSION = '0.1.8.beta'
end

require 'gem/router'
```

However, despite using hundreds of functions and methods of my knowledge, `router.rb` cannot be required!

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Gem is an example, it's actually called Socks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of two things could be happening. If you are on 1.8.7 and friends, Ruby is probably seeing some standard library folder called `gem` (don't name things after standard libraries). If you are using Ruby 1.9.*, you must use a method called `require_relative` that only searches relative to the current working directory.

Comment: I've fixed the problem, it was an error with one of Bundler's defaults in the Gemspec. Thanks for you help.